# fopen() search paths

Tags: c, fopen, search-path

Is there a way to set a search path for fopen() so that when I just enter the filename, it searches these path(s) for this file?

```
f=fopen("xxx","r");
```

I just want xxx not to be in the current directory, and I dont want to change the source code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to code that yourself. If for any reason you can't change the code, you could change your filesystem, e.g. on Linux use symlinks, `bind` mounts, [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) etc.

You could redefine `fopen` for your needs (but I recommend not doing this); on Linux you might even make it "transparent" with dirty [LD_PRELOAD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795) tricks.

Answer (score 1):

No, `fopen` only looks in the current directory, you can't give it a list of directories. But if you want it to search a list of paths:

```
char *paths[] = {
    ".",
    "/etc",
    "/usr/local",
    NULL
};

FILE *fp = NULL;
char path[ENOUGH];

while (!fp && paths[i]) {
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s", paths[i], name);
    fp = fopen(path, "r");

    i++;
}
```

Comment: But the original poster don't want to change his source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't think it's decently possible.